# not knowing how to get the collection id from firestore(flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the pregnancyInfo document ID which is a subcollection from users collection .

why I want to get the document ID? because I want to access the weight subcollection

[image: here is a picture of the firestore]

As you can see from the code below, what am doing is copying and pasting the doc id but each user have a different pregnancy info document ID. So is there a way to retrieve the Document id and store it in a variable?

```
 Future<Widget> getWeight(String weightDate, String weight) async {
String userUid = getUserId();
print('weight date is $weightDate');
QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(userUid)
    .collection('pregnancyInfo')
    .doc("HMEBTKrnOYnmxPmBMHuV")
    .collection('weight')
    .get();
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to read the `HMEBTKrnOYnmxPmBMHuV` value, in which case you'd have to get the documents from `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userUid).collection('pregnancyInfo')`. Did you try that? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question you need to execute a query on the `pregnancyInfo` sub-collection under the `userUid` document.

You will get one or more documents corresponding to one or more "babies".

```
QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(userUid)
    .collection('pregnancyInfo')
    .get();
```

Following your comment, you need to get all the IDs of the `pregnancyInfo` documents (see above Query) and then issue a new Query for each `pregnancyInfo` document.

Comment: let's say I want to access a subcollection inside pregnancyInfo called weight (you can see it in the picture above) , do you know how I can create the query?

Comment: "how I can create the query" => Look at the code in my answer

Comment: I edited my question please read it again, your code will let me access the pregnancy info but I want to access the weight subcollection

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query the pregnancy info across all users, you can [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to read from all `pregnancyInfo`  collections at once.

Similarly, you can use a collection group query on `weight` to read from all weight collections in one go.

Comment: I edited my question please read it again